# Who is considered to be a new user

Tags: support, new-users

In this SE - and others possibly, I haven't really encountered this problem elsewhere yet - but this SE keeps referring to "new users". Who is classified as a new user? Do new users have low reputation or have only been on the site for a couple of days or months? **What classifies a new user from another user who has been around for a while?**

Would I be considered a new user?

This is an example of where it can be seen:

[image]

Comment: We have privileges called [**remove new user restrictions**](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) and [**established user**](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) (which areunlocked at 10 and 1000 rep, respectively), so the cutoff point is probably one of those two levels. But I’m not sure which: I can see an argument for either interpretation.

Comment: Where does it refer to new users, exactly?

Answer (score 6):

In the specific cases you mention - the First Posts and Late Answers review queues - there are strict definitions of "new user".

- The First Posts review queue contains posts from **users who've never posted on the site before**: it literally means *first* posts. This queue was implemented in 2012; see [New Review Queue: First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts) on main meta.
- The Late Answers review queue contains answers from **users with less than 50 rep** which were posted at least 30 days after the question was asked. See [How old does a question have to be for it to be a late answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177552/how-old-does-a-question-have-to-be-for-it-to-be-a-late-answer) on main meta, and note that the rep bar was [raised from 10 to 50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-bypass-the-review-queue) on 29 September 2015.

In general, **there's no strict definition**. Different people use the term "new user" in different ways, according to their own reputation and time on the site. Some people would see me as a new user, since I've only been here since 2014; others probably see me as one of the mainstays of the site. It's all subjective. There are only two possible general definitions I can think of:

- users with **less than 10 reputation**: according to [the help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user), one gets "new user restrictions" removed at this point (though I still think of some users with >1k rep as being new)
- users who've **been around for less than 45 days**: this is the definition used by the [new users tab](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers) in the user list (thanks to @anaranjada for reminding me of this)

> Would I be considered a new user?

I would say **no**. You have over 5000 rep, and you've been a member of this site for longer than two of the moderators - you're no noob :-)